Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Miếu'
This is my models.py
class The_loai(models.Model):
    ten = models.CharField(max_length= 150, unique= True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ten
    
class Thanh_pho(models.Model):
    ten_tp = models.CharField(max_length= 150, unique= True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ten_tp
    
class Quan(models.Model):
    ten_tp = models.ForeignKey(Thanh_pho, on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    ten_quan = models.CharField(max_length= 150, unique= True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ten_quan
    
class Chi_tiet(models.Model):
    ten = models.CharField(max_length= 150, unique= True)
    dia_chi = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique= True)
    the_loai = models.ForeignKey(The_loai, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ten_tp = models.ForeignKey(Thanh_pho, on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    ten_quan = models.ForeignKey(Quan, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    thong_tin = models.TextField()
    hinh_anh = models.ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tentype here

And this is my views.py
def blog(request):
    chi_tiet = Chi_tiet.objects.all().filter(the_loai = "Miếu")
    return render(request, 'blog.html', {'chi_tiet': chi_tiet})

This appeared :
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Miếu'.

I tried to use the_loai's id instead of a name, but nothing was appeared
What i expected is just to show all objects have the word i need
Please help me, Thank you !
